# How much RAM do the different models of iPad have?

Tags: ipad

Read [this](http://www.apple.com/ipad/compare/) link but still trying to figure out how much RAM these different models have. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A very nice visual layout is kept current at: [iOS Support Matrix](http://iossupportmatrix.com/)

The top row has RAM size below the horizontal line showing the late 2016 and early 2017 models have 2, 3, or 4 GB of RAM across the board.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPad):

- 1st generation: 256 MB
- iPad 2 and iPad Mini: 512 MB
- 3rd generation, 4th generation, iPad Air, iPad Mini 2 and iPad Mini 3: 1 GB
- iPad Air 2 and iPad Mini 4: 2 GB
- iPad Pro 10.5 and 12.9-inch: 4 GB
- iPad Pro 9.7-inch: 2 GB