# What are the under documented differences between the iPhone SE, 6s, and 6s plus?

Tags: hardware, iphone

Besides price, size and case design of course, what are the differences between the iPhone SE, 6s, and 6s plus?

Also what about specs that are not listed on Apple site such as the amount of RAM?

Comment: I think they are better than asking small specific questions such as this one: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/217696/how-much-ram-do-the-different-models-of-ipad-have

Comment: Questions on suitability of specific questions are best done in [meta] instead of comments. I'll purge the comments here in a bit... @Mattia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like internally the iPhone SE is similar to the iPhone 6s with an A9 chip with [2GB](http://www.gizmodo.co.uk/2016/03/we-know-how-much-ram-the-iphone-se-uses/) of RAM.

The 6S have (and the SE lacks):

- 16 / 64 / 128 GB storage options
- Dual-domain pixels for wide viewing angles
- Barometer
- Touch ID 2
- MIMO Wi-Fi
- 5 MP front facing camera
- 3D touch
- ultrafast LTE Advanced wireless
- reachability software accommodation (double tap the home button to lower the top half of the display)

The iPhone SE has

- 16 / 64 GB storage options
- single-domain (?? is that even a thing) pixels for less wide viewing angles
- non-MIMO Wi-Fi
- 1.2 MP front facing camera
- ultrafast LTE wireless
- no reachability software accommodation (your fingers need to reach the top of the display)

Comment: "double tap the home button to lower the top half of the display" -- wow. You have no idea how many times I've wondered why this happened when I accidentally double tapped the home button! :D

Comment: @IanC. - there have been several questions on it :-) - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/223885/ios-9-2-double-touch-fingerprint-sensor/223886#223886 & linked