# How do I get more RAM for my iPad mini?

Tags: ios, ipad, hardware

I can’t play Fortnite because of my iPad has only 1 GB of RAM.

Answer (score 16):

RAM is hardware within your iPad that is soldered in place. It can not be upgraded.

The amount of RAM depends on your model of iPad. Newer iPads generally have more RAM.

- [How much RAM do the different models of iPad have?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/217696/37797)

RAM is part of the system on a chip and not replaceable separately even if you disassemble iPad.

> Apple A7 APL0698 SoC
>   Within the A7 package we find SK Hynix H9CKNNN8KTARKR 1 GB LPDDR3 DRAM
>
> [image: Logic board in iPad mini 3]

- [iFixit iPad Mini 3 Wi-Fi Teardown - Step 6](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/iPad+Mini+3+Wi-Fi+Teardown/30628#s71876)

Comment: See [this previous answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/217697/88313) for list of the different iPads and the amount of RAM in each.  You might consider getting a newer model if you want to plan Fortnite and other modern games.

Comment: And there is really *no way* of changing that amount? Like, with a soldering iron?

Comment: @Peter RAM is part of the SoC package so it can't be replaced separately even if you completely disassemble iPad, see edit

Comment: That does leave the question of what'd happen if you desoldered the flash chip and replaced it with a larger model.  Would it be possible to get IOS on the new chip and take advantage of the increased storage space, or would one or more anti-tampering measures provide an unbreachable roadblock?

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider, furthermore, the scale of the parts on something as advanced as an iPad or cell phone means that soldering is done with a microscope.  Very few people have the skill to attempt replacing simple parts like resistors and capacitors.  Larger chips like RAM and processors have solder on the underside of the chip that you can't get to at all.

Comment: Look at Louis Rossman's videos to get an idea what "soldering iron" work on that kind of hardware involves.